# What does this weird notation for normal distribution mean? (from "DUL in FR" paper)

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

I'm trying to understand [this paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2020/papers/Chang_Data_Uncertainty_Learning_in_Face_Recognition_CVPR_2020_paper.pdf). Specifically section 3.3. It's about mapping an image to an embedding but instead of a fixed embedding vector, we map to a distribution. They say the following in 3.2:

> Specifically, we define the representation $z_i$ in latent space of each sample $x_i$ as a Gaussian distribution, $p(z_i|x_i) = \mathcal{N} (z_i; μ_i, σ^2_i I)$

z is the embedding vector, x is the input tensor, I is not defined, i is the index of the input sample.

I am very confused since a probability is a number. How can that be equal to a distribution? Also what in the whatever is that semicolon doing there? What is I?

Their inability to use articles, prepositions, and plurals properly I can guess my way around but their use of mathematical notation makes me want to throw up...

Comment: That $p$ is probably meant to represent a density and by defining it across all possible values of $\mathbf z_i$ represents a distribution.  Meanwhile $\mathcal{N} (\mathbf z_i; \mathbf μ_i, \mathbf σ^2_i I)$ suggests $\mathbf z_i$ has a multivariate normal distribution with mean $\mathbf \mu_i$ and covariance matrix $\mathbf σ^2_i I$ (and given it is multivariate normal, that covariance matrix suggests independence of the components)

Comment: so wait, the I is supposed to be an identity matrix? Is that right?

Comment: Yes.  And all the others in **bold** are vectors